# jquery window does not appear as coded

Tags: jquery

This code should produce a dialog box but is just shows text with a CLOSE button. The code came from the Jquery web site.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Dialog - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function() {
      $("#dialog").dialog();
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
    <p>This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you checked the file paths? For example `/resources/demos/style.css` ? does that exist in your structure?

Comment: I placed your code in a runnable snippet; it seems to work fine. Please check the console for errors

Comment: your code snippet is rendering it properly

Comment: reference jquery before referencing JQuery ui.css

Comment: @KarthikGanesan while putting jquery before css isn't required, is there a reason you recommend it?  Does it make any improvements?  Stop FOUC? (I imagine it would be more likely to cause FOUC).

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to work on my browser (Safari 10.1.1).
Try running from here (Or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ouoo6taf/)), and/or using another browser.
Code:

```js
$( function() {
  $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
} );
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
  <p>This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
</div>
```